# return results from active record relation many_to_many assocation

Tags: ruby, activerecord, many-to-many

I currently have a many_to_many association between `templates` and `types`.
I have an active record relation of `templates`.
I want to return all of the `types` that are linked to those templates.

For example, in an ideal world i would be able to do `templates.types`.
I have tried `templates.joins(:types)`, however this returns `templates` rather then `types`.

So i'm not sure on another way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In pure ruby, without a DB you would want to `flat_map`

```rb
types = templates.flat_map do |template|
  template.types
end

types.uniq # probably you only want unique types
```

This works but is not efficient as soon as you got many Templates/Types since it triggers more queries and loads more objects than needed.

When you have ActiveRecord you can add a `scope` or `self` method (either or, not both as in my example) to `Type`

```rb
class Type < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :template_types
  has_many :templates, through: :template_types

  scope :for_templates, -> (templates) { joins(:template_types).where(template_types: {template: templates}).distinct } # either this or the method below

  def self.for_templates(templates)
    Type.joins(:template_types).where(template_types: {template: templates}).distinct
  end
end
```

(i assumed that the join model is `TemplateType`)

and then do

```rb
templates = Template.some_complicated_query
Type.for_templates(template)
```

I'd recommend you rename `Type` since `type` already has a special meaning with ActiveRecord (Single Table Inheritance).